# integrating the square of probability density?

Tags: r, kernel-density

Suppose I have

```
set.seed(2020)    # make the results reproducible
a <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
```

My probability density is estimated through kernel density estimator (gaussian) in R using the R built in function `density`. The question is how to integrate the square of the estimated density. It does not matter between which values, let us suppose between `-Inf` and `+Inf`. I have tried the following:

```
f <- approxfun(density(a)$x, density(a)$y)
integrate (f*f, min(density(a)$x), max(density(a)$x))
```

Comment: In `approxfun`, `x` and `y` are reversed.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you it was a mistake

Comment: Do you want me to correct it? Done.

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes pleas

Comment: @RuiBarradas i got the following error ; maximum number of subdivsions reached

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error, but the documentation `help('approxfun')` states that the arguments are `x`, `y`, in this order. That's a function `integrate` error, btw.

Comment: @RuiBarradas in fact i got Na yes that is True but even whem i used min and max I got maximum number of subdivisions reached . I forgot to say to you that i was using the whole code above inside a loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221884/discussion-between-rui-barradas-and-z-b).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you very much I decided after thinking to provide you with the code causing troubles better than discussing

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems here. First you have the `x` and `y` round the wrong way in `approxfun`. Secondly, you can't multiply function names together. You need to specify a new function that gives you the square of your original function:

```r
set.seed(2020)   
a  <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
f  <- approxfun(density(a)$x, density(a)$y)
f2 <- function(v) ifelse(is.na(f(v)), 0, f(v)^2)

integrate (f2, -Inf, Inf)
#> 0.2591153 with absolute error < 0.00011
```

We can also plot the original density function and the squared density function:

```r
curve(f, -3, 3)
curve(f2, -3, 3, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: when i try it with -Inf and Inf . I got problems

Comment: even when i use min and max i got maximum number of subdiviosns reached

Comment: @ZB it was returning `NA` outside the range of the density. See my update. It now works with `-Inf` and `Inf`

Comment: in fact i got Na yes that is True but even whem i used min and max I got  maximum number of subdivisions reached . I forgot to say to you that i was using the whole code above inside a loop

Comment: @ZB I don't think anyone here can replicate this fault. Perhaps it is something to do with the loop?

Comment: above is code i have used to calculate the size of tests

Comment: i have tried the first code with -inf and inf and my computer was booting for ever i think it was NAs then i tried it wit min and max so i got maximum number of subdivisons reached Finally i tried the last changement you have done so i got roundoff was detected

Comment: I think i find out the secret !!! for 10000 loops the function do not work well . I think it is limited for 1000

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using package `caTools`, function `trapz`. It computes the integral given a vector `x` and its corresponding image `y` using the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).
I also include a function `trapzf` based on the original to have the integral computed with the function returned by `approxfun`

```
trapzf <- function(x, FUN) trapz(x, FUN(x))

set.seed(2020)    # make the results reproducible
a <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)

d <- density(a)
f <- approxfun(d$x, d$y)

int1 <- trapz(d$x, d$y^2)
int2 <- trapzf(d$x, function(x) f(x)^2)

int1
#[1] 0.2591226

identical(int1, int2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice Rui. What do you think accounts for the small numerical difference in our final answers?

Comment: Function `trapz` uses the trapezoidal rule, I will edit with a link to the Wikipedia page. `integrate` uses adaptive quadrature, the result should not be the same.

Comment: @RuiBarradas superrrrrrrrrrr i will try it and then give you feedback

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write the objective function as `function(x) f(x)**2`, rather than `f*f`, e.g.,

```
> integrate (function(x) f(x)**2, min(density(a)$x), max(density(a)$x))
0.2331793 with absolute error < 6.6e-06
```

Comment: @Allan Cameron Superrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr!!! i will try it and then give you feedback

Comment: I cannot get the same result, I'm getting [Allan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011444/8245406) result. Maybe this is because I have set the RNG seed, unlike the OP.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have no clue what happened. Yours and Allan's code also give me the result I achieved....